# Android trust certificate using an intermeidate CA

Tags: android, certificate

I have created an android app which I can connect to a hardware device (with wifi capabilities) through its wifi
now the manufactures have made this connection secure by using ssl. 
what I have been told these  devices have got an intermediate CA and using it each device generates its own certificates.

I have given this intermediate CA from the device manufacturere
what I am looking for is how to trust this certificate using the intermediate CA and communicate to these devices?

I use retrofit for communication and used keystore in another application, but I am still a beginner in certificates and trust manager area

some code snippets use before

```
Keystore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
fis = context.getResources().openRawResource(BuildConstants.keyStoreFile()); // bks certificate in raw folder
ks.load(fis, BuildConstants.keyStorePass());
```

this key store is used in the trust manager factory for retrofit ssl connection

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public TrustManagerFactory provideTrustManagerFactory(Context context) {

    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = null;
    KeyStore keyStore = null;
    try {
        trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TRUST_MANAGER_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);

        if (BuildConfig.USE_CUSTOM_CERT) {
            Timber.d("We are using custom cert ......");
            keyStore = getKeyStore(context); //loads the bks keystre
        } else {
            Timber.d("We are not using custom cert, and have no certificate i.e ..this must be a free pass......");
        }

        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        Timber.e("Failed to create TrustManager factory: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return trustManagerFactory;
}
```

thanks in advance and sorry if I havent explained the scenario properly